# Generate digital controlling signal with some conditions

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, flipflop, logic-gates

I am having a problem as below. Hope somebody could help me out. 
I have a clock signal with a fixed frequency. Now I need to generate 3 control signals **`S1`**, **`S2`**, **`S3`** as follows:

**S1**: turn on at rising edge of CLK and keeping on until **condition 1** is met.
**S2**: turn on right after S1 is off and keeping on until **condition 2** is met.
**S3**: turn on for the remaining portion of the clock period.

Condition 1, 2 are signals Vc1, Vc2 go from LOW to HIGH respectively.

Let's assume that normally Vo1, Vo2 are below Vref1, Vref2 but very close to Vref1, Vref2 so that the condition 1, 2 are always satisfied before another clock arrives.

Note:

1. S1, S2, S3 are only ON one time in a clock period
2. I'd like to use only logic gates, flip flops and don't want to use microcontrollers or another clock signal.
3. ON, OFF here means high and low level, respectively.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because looks like homework without any effort shown to solve it.

Comment: Smells too much like homework, which is OK, but you **must** show what you have done to solve this. I mean, we're not going to solve it for you. Also since you do not have a (clock) event for 1 => 0 of S1 you cannot make this without implementing delays or (RC) time constants. I mean, what determines the time when S1 will do 1 => 0 ?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: I am not at school anymore. I am trying to generate control signals for my dc-dc converter. I tried but there is a problem that S1, S2, S3 ON many times in a period.

Comment: S1 will do 1 => 0 when condition 1 is met as I said above. Condition 1 is met mean there is a another controlling signal go from LOW to HIGH.

Comment: You are missing some requirements. 1) What happens if another CLK comes along, 2) What happens if condition 2 or 3 is already true when CLK comes along. It would also be nicer if your logic diagram showed the condition signals. And homework or not, you should really show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "come along". I tried to generalize the problem so I can make the post short and easy but maybe I need to draw a detailed one.

Comment: Trying to "make the post short" is not a good idea if it leaves room for guessing / assumptions and/or the information is incomplete. It is unclear what "condition 1" means, if these are signals then include them in the timing diagram.

Comment: "Comes along" means another clock arrives before condition 1 and condition 2 arrive.

Comment: @anhnha What kind of solution do you expect? Or prefer? software on a µC or combinatorial / sequential logic with transistors? Or some logical gates (AND / OR / NAND / NOR / XOR).

Comment: I want to design all blocks from logic gates, flip flops. I am making a detailed drawing so I will update it in a 15 minutes.

Comment: @Trevor: Let's assume that normally Vo1, Vo2 are below Vref1, Vref2 but very close to Vref1, Vref2 so that the condition 1, 2 are always satisfied before another clock arrives.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: my initial design: S1 = Invert of Vc1. S2 = Invert of Vc1 AND Invert of Vc2 (AND here is logic AND). S3 = NOR of (S1, S2). However, S1, S2, S3 may ON many times in a clock period.

Comment: OH MY.. now we have gone analog????

Comment: *I want to design all blocks from logic gates, flip flops* OK, then why are there current sources, capacitors and comparators in your schematic? Also using ideal current sources like that (with switches in series which could be open meaning infinite voltage) is asking for trouble. Why not simply use RC for timing?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: It is a dc-dc converter with 3 outputs. The current source is just a model for inductor. There is no infitite voltage if there is always path for the current source by switching S1, S2, S3 ON alternatively. With all blocks I meant to say the controller to generate that control signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question became totally unclear, but I'm posting this anyway, just because I did the time... and found another cute simulator [on-line](https://logic.ly/demo/).

[image]

Comment: Can you send the link with that simulation file or post the waveforms?

Comment: @anhnha nope, it wont let me, but you can throw it together quickly enough through that link.

Comment: This simulator is very hard to make a wire connection!!!

Comment: @anhnha ya its a bit weird. Just pick up a pin and drop it on the destination. YOu can square the rubber bands up later.

Comment: your idea somehow works but there is a small problem that after Q2 is OFF, Q3 is ON forever not just the remaining portion of the clock period.

Comment: @anhnha that is not a problem of the circuit, that is a problem of your defined requirements. As is, Q3 will stay on till condition 2 goes away.

Comment: Maybe you misread the my requirement. As I said above, S3 turns on for the remaining portion of the clock period. However, I think we can modify to make that works.

Comment: @anhnha and as I said..you failed to indicate what happens when the clock arrives while the conditions are already met

Comment: Well, maybe you still have some problem with my requirement. I defined in one period. First, Q1, Q2 is OK. Q3 also ON after Q2 which is OK but it should be turned off at the end of period. Which is what I mean by saying S3 is ON for the remaining portion of the clock period above.

Comment: I can make it now just by a small modification. Thanks for helps.